# Ruby Argument error in convert function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arguments

I am trying to run a program from a book that I am learning ruby from, but I keep getting this error no matter how I try to fix it

```
ex41.rb:70:in `convert': wrong number of arguments (0 for 2) (ArgumentError)
    from ex41.rb:117:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from ex41.rb:113:in `each'
    from ex41.rb:113:in `block in <main>'
    from ex41.rb:108:in `loop'
    from ex41.rb:108:in `<main>'
```

I do understand that I have the wrong number of arguments, but the thing is I can't find where I'm getting them wrong, could someone please explain this to me? For convienience I put (LINE XXX(as a number)) by the lines that cause me trouble. Thank you.

```
# calls external file from web
require 'open-uri'

# assigns WORD_URL to website
WORD_URL = "http://learncodethehardway.org/words.txt"
# creates empty array WORDS
WORDS =[]

# creates hash PHRASES
PHRASES = {
  "class ### < ### \nend" =>
    "Make a class named ### that is-a ###.",
  # my assumption is that @@@ ### and the like will sb in words, lets find 
  out
  "class ###\n\tdef initialize(@@@)\n\tend\nend" =>
    "class ### has-a initialize that takes @@@ parameters.",
  "class ###\n\tdef ***(@@@)\n\tend\nend" =>
    "class ### has-a function named *** that takes @@@ parameters.",
  "*** = ###.new()" =>
    "Set *** to an instance of class ###.",
  "***.***(@@@)" =>
    "From *** get the *** function, and call it with parameters @@@",
  "***.*** = '***'" =>
    "From ***, get the *** attribute and set it equal to '***'."
}

# creates variable for first argument if argument is english
PHRASE_FIRST = ARGV[0] == "english"

 # opens WORD_URL function and creates function f
 open(WORD_URL) {|f|
  # for every line in f chomps break character and pushes out word to f
  f.each_line {|word| WORDS.push(word.chomp)}
}

# defines function craft_names with variables rand_words, snippet and 
pattern, and assigns caps value to false
def craft_names(rand_words, snippet, pattern, caps=false)
  # assigns vriable names to snippet.scan on pattern maps and does the 
following 
function
  names = snippet.scan(pattern).map do
    # assigns word to rand_words that have popped off the end
    word = rand_words.pop()
    # Guessing again, maybe capitalizes the first word
    caps ? word.capitalize : word
    # ends do
  end

  # returns names twice
  return names * 2
  # ends craft_names function
end

    # defines function craft_params with variables rand_words snippet, and 
      pattern
def craft_params(rand_words, snippet, pattern)
# assigns names to action scan  with variable pattern with action 
# length on beginning part of array to snippet and runs the following 
# function using map
  names = (0...snippet.scan(pattern).length).map do
    # assigns variable param_count to an action that takes a random 3 and adds one to it
    param_count = rand(3) + 1
    # assigns variable params to one long ass action that maps 0 to param_count 
value and pops out the last word
    params = (0...param_count).map { |x| rand_words.pop() }
    # joins params list, (I'm sure its a list) with string ,
    params.join(", ")
    # ends names for loop
  end

  # returns names twice
  return names * 2
# ends craft_params function
end

# defines convert function with variables snippet and phrase
(LINE 70) def convert(snippet, phrase)
  # sords words randomly and assigns words to rand_words
  rand_words = WORDS.sort_by {rand}
  # assigns class names to function craft mnames on rand_words, snippet /###/, and caps=true
  class_names = craft_names(rand_words, snippet, /###/, caps=true)
  # assigns other_names to craft_names with variables rand_words, snippet, and /\*\*\*/
  other_names = craft_names(rand_words, snippet, /\*\*\*/)
  # assigns param_names to craft_params with rand_words, snippet, and @@@ as variables
  param_names = craft_params(rand_words, snippet, /@@@/)

  # assigns  empty array results
  results = []


  # on all variables snippet and phrase matchups perform the function 
 sentence
 [snippet, phrase].each do |sentence|

    # fake class names, also copies sentence
    result = sentence.gsub(/###/) {|x| param_names.pop}

    # fake other names
    result.gsub!(/\*\*\*/)

    # fake parameter lists
    result.gsub!(/@@@/)

    # returns result
    results.push(result)
    # ends function
  end

  # returns results
  return results
   # ends convert function
end

# keep going until they hit ctrl-d
# continual loop
(LINE 108)loop do
  # assigns variable snippets to Prases.keys  and sorts randomly
  snippets = PHRASES.keys().sort_by {rand}

 # for snippet in snippets
  (LINE113) snippets.each do |snippet|
    # assigns PHRASES on snippet to phrase
    phrase = PHRASES[snippet]
    # asssigns question and answer to converted snippet and phrase 
    #respectively
    (LINE117)question, answer = convert[snippet, phrase]

    # if values in phrase firs are equal to answer, question
    if PHRASE_FIRST
       # question, answer = answer, question
      question, answer = answer, question
    # ends if
    end
    # prints question, two line breaks, and > without line break
    print question, "\n\n> "

    # closes program unless input
    exit(0) unless $stdin.gets

    # prints line break ANSWER: answer line break line break
      puts "\nANSWER: %s\n\n"

    # ends unless
  end
  # ends loop
end
```

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR – Use `convert(snippet, phrase)` instead of `convert[snippet, phrase]`

---

When you write

```
convert[snippet, phrase]
```

... it is equivalent to:

```
convert()[snippet, phrase]
```

Adding a space:

```
convert [snippet, phrase]
```

... would call the method with an array:

```
convert([snippet, phrase])
```

To actually call the method with two arguments, use:

```
convert(snippet, phrase)
```

or

```
convert snippet, phrase
```